# YARN: Application Master resource allocation

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

I have a 5 node hadoop cluster running HDP 2.3. I was wondering how the resource manager decides how much resources to allocate for application masters.

On opening the scheduler tab of the resource manager UI and expanding a queue for usage details one can find the following properties

1. Max Application Master Resources
2. Used Application Master Resources
3. Max Application Master Resources Per User

On opening the mapred-site.xml file, I find the property `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb` set to a value of 682mb.

However on opening a hive terminal, I always see application master containers getting 1024mb with 1 vcore.

Is it the case that application masters have different requirements for different types of applications?

I was hoping someone could direct me to the properties that decide the above metrics.

Comment: Look at `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` property in yarn-site.xml. It defines granularity per container for resource scheduler. So, you can operate only with memory slots which are equal to a value of this property. As a result, 682mb becomes, for example 1024mb, if this property is set to 1024mb.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @DmitryY. I forgot to mention that hive is using the tez engine. So the application master requirements are dictated by configurations in tez, specifically the property tez.am.resource.memory.mb was set to 1024 and tez.am.resource.cpu.vcores was set to 1.